# sed, replace globally a delimiter with the first part of the line

Tags: perl, sed

Lets say I have the following lines:

```
1:a:b:c
2:d:e:f
3:a:b
4:a:b:c:d:e:f
```

how can I edit this with sed (or perl) in order to read:

```
1a1b1c
2d2e2f
3a3b
4a4b4c4d4e4f
```

I have done with awk like this:

```
awk -F':' '{gsub(/:/, $1, $0); print $0}'
```

but takes ages to complete! So looking for something faster.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a script or is it more of a one time thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Tis a tad tricky, but it can be done with `sed` (assuming the file `data` contains the sample input):

```
$ sed '/^\(.\):/{
s//\1/
: retry
s/^\(.\)\([^:]*\):/\1\2\1/
t retry
}' data
1a1b1c
2d2e2f
3a3b
4a4b4c4d4e4f
$
```

You may be able to flatten the script to one line with semi-colons; `sed` on MacOS X is a bit cranky at times and objected to some parts, so it is split out into 6 lines.  The first line matches lines starting with a single character and a colon and starts a sequence of operations for when that is recognized.  The first substitute replaces, for example, '1:' by just '1'.  The `: retry` is a label for branching too - a key part of this.  The next substitution copies the first character on the line over the first colon.  The `t retry` goes back to the label if the substitute changed anything.  The last line delimits the entire sequence of operations for the initially matched line.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    if ( s/^([^:]+)// ) {
        my $delim = $1;
        s/:/$delim/g;
    }
    print;
}

__DATA__
1:a:b:c
2:d:e:f
3:a:b
4:a:b:c:d:e:f
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use feature qw/ say /;
use strict;
use warnings;
while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my @elements = split /:/;
    my $interject = shift @elements;
    local $" = $interject;
    say $interject, "@elements";
}

__DATA__
1:a:b:c
2:d:e:f
3:a:b
4:a:b:c:d:e:f
```

Or on the linux shell command line:

`perl -aF/:/ -pe '$i=shift @F;$_=$i.join $i,@F;' infile.txt`

Comment: Which versions of Perl support `use feature qq/ say /;`, out of curiosity?

Comment: From what I recall, 5.10 and up.  Otherwise, just use `print $interject, "@elements\n";`  say is really just a shortcut that saves a few keystrokes.  Aside from that there's nothing special about it.

Comment: I should add that I used `<DATA>` and `__DATA__` as a shortcut to include the input data in the working example.  If you're reading from a file specified on the command line, and were invoking the Perl script (as opposed to the Perl one-liner), you would change `<DATA>` to `<>` and omit the `__DATA__` segment.  But you probably already figured that out. ;)