# Can i mention the backreference from different pattern to other pattern in sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Suppose i have this data

```
1:a:b:c
2:d:e:f
3:a:b
4:a:b:c:d:e:f
```

and the output i want is

```
1a1b1c
2d2e2f
3a3b
4a4b4c4d4e4f
```

I got that from [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566007/sed-replace-globally-a-delimiter-with-the-first-part-of-the-line/6566128#6566128)

The solution which i was trying was this

`sed -re 's/^([0-9]):/\1/g;s/:/L/g' temp.txt`

I have two different patterns. I just want to know that can i use `\1` in the second pattern

like this

`sed -re 's/^([0-9]):/\1/g;s/:/\1/g' temp.txt`

Comment: if you just want to remove `:` then do `sed 's;:;;g' temp.txt'`

Comment: but i want to replace with first numeric on the each line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do it that way, but there's another way to do it:

```
sed ':a;s/^\([0-9]*\):\([^:]*\):/\1:\2\1/;ta;s/://' input
```

### Explanation

```
do {                                                           // a:
  1) match numbers at the beginning and a `:`                  // ^\([0-9]*\):
  2) match and remember everything that is not `:` upto an `:` // \([^:]*\):
  3) swap the `:` with the number from 1 (keep the first `:`)  // /\1:\2\1/
} while (there are matches)                                    // ta
finally delete the `:` after the number                        // s/://
```

Comment: Thanks buddy , u did it again. can you have a look at the question above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566007/sed-replace-globally-a-delimiter-with-the-first-part-of-the-line/6566128#6566128 , why high rep people are giving comlex answers , but your looks simple and easy. May be i am missing something

Comment: don't know what to say:) why did you ask the same question?

Comment: Actually i was trying to solve the same question using the way i mentioned in question , and i wanted to know if thats possible or not

Comment: not possible with sed. the answer above intentionally keeps the first column and matches it in a loop for the same effect

Comment: what will happen if we chnage `/;ta` to `/;ba`.

Comment: that will create an infinite loop since `b` is unconditional jump

Comment: but u mentioned here `{N;ba};` in previous question . wont that be the unconditional loop

Comment: that block is only executed when `$!` is true so it won't loop when the input ends

Answer (score 5):

A capture group can only be used in a substitution command it was created in. This is a great resource for learning `sed`: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

A better way to tackle your problem, would be to use `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{ OFS=$1; $1="" }1' file
```

Results:

```
1a1b1c
2d2e2f
3a3b
4a4b4c4d4e4f
```

Explanation:

The `-F` flag sets the field separator to a colon (`-F:`). Then, for each line of input, set the output field separator to the first field (`OFS="$1"`) and 'delete' the first field (or rather just set it to null; `$1=""`). The `1` on the end, enables default printing. HTH.

Comment: I tried this only and it didn't work `awk -F: '{ OFS=$1; }1' temp.txt` can you explain wasn't that supposed to work. nothing gets replaced

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I didn't copy/paste the right command. Please see the explanation. HTH.

Comment: @Stevee why is the script not working if i remove this `$1=""`. i just want to test

Comment: You simply need to in some way force `awk` to rebuild the line. Setting `$1=""` achieves this. Simply setting `OFS` will not do anything. I hope that makes sense. I'll see if I can find you a better explanation somewhere.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html) at `$1 = $1` as a means to change field separators. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/^(([^:]*):.*):|:/\1\2/;ta' file
```